# iOS LinkedIn User Feeds and Recent Activities

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

I'm using iOS LinkedIn SDK and able to get user details via

```
 let targetURLString = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(public-profile-url,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url)?format=json"
```

But how can I fetch user User Feeds and Recent Activities?